# Checkout shared library with tag with legacySCm

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So trying to checkout shared library by tag. This works perfectly with moderSCM, but for reasons we need to use other way (legacySCM);

```
def lib = library identifier: 'jenkins-shared-library@41', 
          retriever: legacySCM([$class: 'GitSCM', 
          userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'account', 
         url: 'https://website.com.repo.git']]])
```

Doing that results to:

```
00:00:01.518  Loading library jenkins-shared-library@41
00:00:01.521  Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
```

However it does not checkout the tag "41". It just checkouts master. Why is the case?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work and I don't know why it isn't.

It is unusual for someone to load a shared library dynamically using the `library` step instead of using the `@library` annotation. Since you are specifying a `retriever`, why don't you pass the tag to it?

You can find out all the options for `GitSCM` by going to the [snippet generator](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/pipelines/pipeline-dev-tools) and trying the `library` step.

This is what I came up with:

```
library changelog: false, identifier: 'jenkins-shared-library', retriever: legacySCM([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '41']], extensions: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'account', url: 'https://website.com.repo.git']]])
```

but I personally like to structure my code a bit more

```
final Object lib = library(
    [
        identifier: 'jenkins-shared-library',
        changelog: false,
        retriever: legacySCM(
            [
                $class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [
                    [
                        name: '41'
                    ]
                ],
                extensions: [],
                userRemoteConfigs: [
                    [
                        credentialsId: 'account',
                        url: 'https://website.com.repo.git'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

I hope that specifying the tag via the GitSCM works for you.

I think you should drop by https://community.jenkins.io/ and post about what you are trying to do in your pipeline. When you load a library dynamically because you lose one of the main benefits which is that shared libraries arent subjected to script security, at least when they are loaded via the `@library` annotation.